# Regex to edit latex tables

Tags: regex, latex

I have a LaTeX table (below is snippet) that contains two values (value 1: standard error; value 2: estimate) after every \underset.  I would like to edit by adding \bf{} to the second value after every \underset, so long as the second value divided by the first value is greater than 2 OR less than -2.

For example, after the first \underset (after the 'intercept'), -9.686/1.742 is < -2, therefore I want the original {-9.686} to read as \bf{-9.686}.  I have hundreds of variables, so going through manually is not preferred. I'm only working w/ notepad ++, but could try Python if necessary. Any tips for the regex and/or suitable platform (editor/parser,etc) for PC would be much appreciated.

```
documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}  % Additional math packages

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hptb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline

(Intercept)&$\underset{(1.742)}{-9.686}$&$\underset{(0.907)}     
{-9.085}$&$\underset{(0.663)}{-9.724}$&$\underset{(0.565)}{-9.077}$&$\underset{(0.619)} 
{-7.601}$&$\underset{(0.838)}{-5.273}$&$\underset{(1.120)}{-3.417}$\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I would like the output table to read like this.

Output table:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hptb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline

(Intercept)&$\underset{(1.742)}{\bf{-9.686}}$&$\underset{(0.907)}
{\bf{-9.085}}$&$\underset{(0.663)}{-9.724}$&$\underset{(0.565)}{\bf{-
-9.077}}$&$\underset{(0.619)}{\bf{-7.601}}$&$\underset{(0.838)} 
{-5.273}$&$\underset{(1.120)}{-1.417}$\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can already forget notepad++

Answer (score 5):

This can be done entirely in LaTeX...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,collcell,array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmathm,collcell,array}
\makeatletter
\def\insertbf@$\underset#1#2${$\underset{#1}{\mathbf{#2}}$}
\newcommand{\insertbf}[1]{\expandafter\insertbf@#1}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\insertbf}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hptb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l||*{7}{c|}} \hline
    (Intercept) & $\underset{(1.742)}{-9.686}$ & $\underset{(0.907)}{-9.085}$ & $\underset{(0.663)}{-9.724}$
      & $\underset{(0.565)}{-9.077}$ & $\underset{(0.619)}{-7.601}$ & $\underset{(0.838)}{-5.273}$ 
      & $\underset{(1.120)}{-3.417}$
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{|l||*{7}{C|}} \hline
    (Intercept) & $\underset{(1.742)}{-9.686}$ & $\underset{(0.907)}{-9.085}$ & $\underset{(0.663)}{-9.724}$
      & $\underset{(0.565)}{-9.077}$ & $\underset{(0.619)}{-7.601}$ & $\underset{(0.838)}{-5.273}$ 
      & $\underset{(1.120)}{-3.417}$
  \end{tabular}  
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, both tables are the same with the top one using the regular `c`-column specification, while the bottom one uses a newly-defined `C`-column specification. The latter intercepts the setting of `\underset` to modify the font of the second argument.

The [`collcell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) is used to capture each of the cell's contents in columns 2-8. They have to exactly match the form `$\underset{#1}{#2}$` so that it can be transformed into `$\underset{#1}{\mathbf{#2}}$`. The [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) eases the cell collection via a newly defined column (simplifying the code).

Some things to note:

- I used a replication column specifier `*{<num>}{<col spec>}` which repeats column specification `<col spec>` a total of `<num>` times. It makes for more readable code.
- Use `\mathbf` instead of the text-related `\bf`. See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)
- Rather than duplicating the same primitive concept over-and-over, define a macro that you can use (see [Consistent typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764)). This way it gives you a hook into the contents that you can easily manipulate if you change your mind. For example,

  ```
  \newcommand{\stderrest}[2]{$\underset{(#1)}{#2}$}% \stderrest{<stderr>}{<est>}
  ```

  and then use `\stderrest{<stderr>}{<est>}` wherever you need this kind of thing set. That way, an update to the formatting is as easy as

  ```
  \renewcommand{\stderrest}[2]{$\underset{(#1)}{\mathbf{#2}}$}% \stderrest{<stderr>}{<est>}
  ```

  and you're done.
- Don't use the `center` environment inside your float; rather use `\centering`. As reference, see [Should I use `\center` or `\centering` for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/5764)
- The use of the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair is just because I defined a specific "internal" command that matches the input of your specification. It's not really necessary and can be changed. But for more information on this, see [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)
- If you have a cell in the newly-defined `C`-column that does not have an `$\underset{#1}{#2}$` form, you need to use `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{..}` to avoid it being collected.

---

> ... is there anyway to add a conditional statement that only inserts the `\mathbf` prior to `{#2}` if and only if the absolute value of `{#2}` divided by `{#1}` is greater than 2? As of now, it adds the `\mathbf` to every value in `{#2}`.

For conditional formatting of variable, here's one option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,collcell,array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmathm,collcell,array}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\makeatletter
\let\stderr@format\relax
\def\stripparen@(#1){#1}% Remove parentheses
\def\insertbf@$\underset#1#2${%
  \FPabs\resultA{#2}% Absolute value of #2
  \edef\resultB{\stripparen@#1}% Extract std err
  \FPeval\result{\resultA / \resultB}% Divide est / std err
  \FPifgt\result{2}\let\stderr@format\mathbf\fi%
  $\underset{#1}{\stderr@format{#2}}$}%
\newcommand{\insertbf}[1]{\expandafter\insertbf@#1}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\insertbf}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hptb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l||*{7}{c|}} \hline
    (Intercept) & $\underset{(1.742)}{-9.686}$ & $\underset{(0.907)}{-9.085}$ & $\underset{(0.663)}{-9.724}$
      & $\underset{(0.565)}{-9.077}$ & $\underset{(0.619)}{-7.601}$ & $\underset{(0.838)}{-5.273}$ 
      & $\underset{(1.120)}{-3.417}$
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{|l||*{7}{C|}} \hline
    (Intercept) & $\underset{(1.742)}{-9.686}$ & $\underset{(0.907)}{-9.085}$ & $\underset{(0.663)}{-9.724}$
      & $\underset{(0.565)}{-9.077}$ & $\underset{(0.619)}{-7.601}$ & $\underset{(0.838)}{-5.273}$ 
      & $\underset{(1.120)}{-3.417}$
  \end{tabular}  

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{|l||*{7}{C|}} \hline
    (Intercept) & $\underset{(1.742)}{-2.686}$ & $\underset{(0.907)}{-9.085}$ & $\underset{(0.663)}{-9.724}$
      & $\underset{(0.565)}{-9.077}$ & $\underset{(0.619)}{-7.601}$ & $\underset{(0.838)}{-1.273}$ 
      & $\underset{(1.120)}{-3.417}$
  \end{tabular}  
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[`fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) provides the fixed-point arithmetic to condition of the value of certain variables. I'm sure the updated code is self-explanatory.

Comment: This is great, is there anyway to add a conditional statement that only  inserts the \mathbf prior to {#2} if and only if the absolute value of   {#2} divided by  {#1} is greater than 2?

Comment: As of now, it adds the \mathbf to every value in {#2}.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An example with Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

data = r'''documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}  % Additional math packages

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hptb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline

(Intercept)&$\underset{(1.742)}{-9.686}$&$\underset{(0.907)}     
{-9.085}$&$\underset{(0.663)}{-9.724}$&$\underset{(0.565)}{-9.077}$&$\underset{(0.619)} 
{-7.601}$&$\underset{(0.838)}{-5.273}$&$\underset{(1.120)}{-3.417}$\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}'''

print re.sub(r'(\\underset{\()(-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)(\)}\s*{)(-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)(?=}\$)',
    lambda m: m.group(1)+m.group(2)+m.group(3)+'\\bf{'+m.group(4)+'}'
        if abs(float(m.group(4))/float(m.group(2)))>2 else m.group(0), data)
```

In short, the idea is to capture the two values to pass to the lambda function that compares the absolute value of the quotient to 2 and returns the modified string or the whole match.